# ¿Cómo puedo remover la barra de desplazamiento lateral en Calendly?

Tags: scroll, scrollbar

Mi enfoque es el siguiente:

```javascript
const ReservaCitaModal: React.FC<ReservaCitaModalProps> = ({ opened, onClose }) => {


    function handleClick() {
        // @ts-ignore
        window.Calendly.initPopupWidget({
            url: 'https://calendly.com/david_carreno/citas?text_color=4e4d4d&primary_color=789bec',
        });
        return false;
    }



    return (
        <>
            <Modal.Root opened={opened} onClose={onClose} centered size={'xl'} >
                <Modal.Overlay color='rgba(78, 77, 77, 0.65)' />
                <Modal.Content radius={25} px={10} pt={10} >
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>
                            <div className="title-modal-reserve-appointment flex justify-start">
                                <Calendar className="mr-2" /> Reserva tu cita
                            </div>
                        </Modal.Title>
                        <Modal.CloseButton />
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body className="description-modal-reserve-appointment ">
                        <Divider size={2} mb={15} w={'40%'} />
                        <div>
                            ¿Listo para reservar tu cita? Elige la opción que más te convenga: puedes utilizar  <strong>Calendly </strong>para una reserva rápida haciéndolo tú mismo, o contactarnos por  <strong>WhatsApp </strong>para una atención personalizada. Selecciona abajo la que más se ajuste a tu necesidad.
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex justify-center gap-5 py-8" >
                            <ActionIcon
                                variant="white"
                                size="150px"
                                className="shadow-2xl shadow-[2px 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)]"
                                radius={20}
                            >
                                <Image src={'./homePage/whatsapp_logo.svg'} alt="ícono whatsapp" h={90} />
                            </ActionIcon>
                            <ActionIcon
                                onClick={handleClick}
                                variant="white"
                                size="150px"
                                className="shadow-2xl shadow-[2px 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)]"
                                radius={20}
                            >
                                <Image src={'./homePage/calendly_logo.svg'} alt="ícono whatsapp" h={100} />
                            </ActionIcon>
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal.Content>
                <Script
                    id="calendly-embed"
                    strategy='afterInteractive'
                    src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"
                    type="text/javascript"
                    async
                />
                <link
                    href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                />
            </Modal.Root>
            

        </>
    );
};

export default ReservaCitaModal;
```

A demás con este enfoque me sale lo siguiente en consola y tampoco he podido con eso.
246Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
anchor:4

```bash
 GET https://me.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=C51zmWbjz8tuLxjHqVFx3KcZkEHMyHB2CJnSnYG3Pydbvm-Re_xeuoyO1ty5PRrWV5N5pNsngiq1AC-8hY6zKFy8eapiqpzqjtBbA1w62c0G9fRr0d092OmkWEP3l4NEgpYME7tbQI8iyvXlH7Vw7nCDKnrB-Evixrglqo5Tuv8CphCnQ4kYRr4p2cYhSsin_3eLa9zmt7hhz26TPJXkb9e0EkMqW31TGp2MKABdzMOquUHHfv4Lq4pyNYdrouVlfBEbnIvvM_nSYTTYDQeTRPzXCNaaQpT_9jSLgIUcht8 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200 (OK)
```

Si alguiente tiene una solución, agradecería.